# Role based security asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security

I'm interested in knowing what are the best practices for using role based security in MVC: 
how to secure your actions and make them accessible by specific roles only?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you setup your ASP.Net membership provider correctly, you can easily use the [Authorize]-attribute to specify access for different roles or users.

To require users to login, use:

```
[Authorize]
public class SomeController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

To restrict access for specific roles, use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public class SomeController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

And to restrict access for specific users, use:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Charles, Linus")]
public class SomeController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize(Users = "Charles, Linus")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

Comment: What if you wish your roles/permissions to be dynamic in the DB?

Comment: @JoePhilllips Create a custom attribute, and onAuthorize handler.

Comment: I like the Authorize method decoration. Here's a follow up question: if we have an active directory group created to deal with exceptions to the rule.. e.g. a group named "MyApp_AccessDenied" .. is there a way to use that.. i.e. a negative version of the Authorize decoration...  like a DenyAuthorize decoration?