# How do I secure an asp.net mvc action method that returns data to a variety of consumers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I have a customer controller with a method to get all customers and I want to protect it. Only allow verified consumers to get the data, how would I go about this? For example: If a windows app needs to get all customers, how would my mvc application know to allow the windows app to make the request?

Comment: MVC is web, windows app is not.  Do you really need to have a windows app access your website other than through normal web channels?

Answer (score 0):

Implement MVC role based security and require the windows app users to provide log-in information. Here's another SO thread that might help [Role based security asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356102/role-based-security-asp-net-mvc)