# Page Permission based on Role ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way of implementing a mechanism where the system check the user role before permitting it to access some specific page? Also to enable maybe some link/action in the page, for example for users that have 'Super' role, they might be able to delete/edit the data while the rest can only see it?

For your information, I do not use the out of the box User management from the ASP.NET MVC (where the user is created in the .mdf database embedded to webapp), but I have developed my own user module (for authenticating, registering and deleting user).

So ..what is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356102/role-based-security-asp-net-mvc

Comment: seriously downvote for what people?

Comment: because you can search first ;) or see suggestions.

Comment: I guess if you don't want to answer that is fine. But downvote is just lame. Did you see the answer for this question is much better. Provide us with more alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write a custom `ValidationAttribute`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx

Basically, you inherit from `ValidationAttribute`, and override `IsValid()`:

```
public class IsAnAdminAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    protected override bool IsValid(object obj) {
        if (Membership.UserInRole("admin"))
            return true; // they can access it
        else
            return false; // can't access it
    }
}
```

..then you apply it to controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[IsAnAdmin]
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    // only administrators can access this now
}
```

Comment: Supposed that I have two roles `admin` and `normal` and a controller method `MonitorTraffic`. How can I filter so that only `admin` can have the access to this page in this controller method? Sorry kind of new to MVC4 myself. From the example given, I failed to see how the annotation can do that. Maybe could you please show me an example?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The attribute is fired by MVC because it inherits from `ValidationAttribute`. It will call the `IsValid` method and if `IsValid` returns `true`, access will be granted. If it returns `false`, access will be denied.

Comment: Understood. But where can I create this class? I mean proper place to put it? Not in model i guess? Sorry, newbie question again

Comment: No worries. They are a front-end solution.. so I would put them in a "Code" folder in the UI project (your MVC project).